# Грамматически правильное продолжение предложения: "Говоря о богатстве языка,.."

Tags: лексика

1. "...в аудитории началась дискуссия".
2. "...у меня возник интерес к этой проблеме".
3. "...требуются конкретные примеры".
4. "...мы имеем в виду главным оброзом его словарный запас".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Четвертый вариант будет правильным, только после слова "языка" должна быть запятая, так как предложение начинается с деепричастного оборота.

Answer (score 1):

вариант 4, так как добавочное действие деепричастия говоря относится к определяемому слову, выраженному словосочетанием с глаголом имеем в виду. Но почему написано "оброзом"?

Answer (score 0):

здесь вариант 4!)

Answer (score 0):

здесь вариант 4!)